# How to send request meeting calendar without additional in delphi

Tags: outlook, icalendar, delphi-2010, rad

I wrote icalendar mail programme. I want to send request meeting calendar. I done and I am sending document. But I want to do icalendar code without additional. What should I do?[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "additional"?

Comment: Additional mean; when I send meeting request calendar, Calendar is coming  meeting.ics in above document. I want to direct calendar.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean without the user bothering to accept your invitation? You can't do that by design - the user must accept your invitation. If you want to create an appointment directly in the Calendar folder, use EWS - but you will need to have the right to access the user's Calendar folder.

Comment: My design will be meeting request calendar in outlook. I did with code but is not working as I want. My code is creating  meeting.ics file. when meeting.ics file double-click, is working. Purpose is direct meeting request calendar  without meeting.ics

Comment: So the problem is that your invitation is an attachment? You need to describe your problem a bit better. Show how the meeting invitation is created - the outer MIME message needs to have the right content type and the body of the message must be a single part (iCal).

Comment: How can I send message source

Comment: It is your program that creates and sends a message in the MIME format, right?

Comment: Yes, it is true. I am sending meeting request mail . Mail is including icalendar format.

Comment: I understand that. Please post the resulting MIME message that you send.